# Intellij: use underscore default in branch naming

Tags: git, intellij-idea, git-branch

I am using the latest version of IntelliJ. The behavior in automatic space replacing seems different, when I am creating a new branch.
For example, if I've named a branch "test branch" in the past, IntelliJ automatically converted the name in `test_branch`.

But now, it becomes `test-branch`. I've tried to search how to set the old behavior in settings, but with no results. Do you know where I can set this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found it! It is not in the git settings, but in `Advanced Settings`.

[image]